# Compiling SDL from source on a Mac running OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: c++, sdl, osx-lion

I've downloaded the SDL source SDL-1.2.14.zip from the libsdl website and gotten to the make step.
When I `./configure`, I have no issues.  However, when I `make`, it gets what seems like a long way through the compilation process and dies with this output:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -g -O2  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -DTARGET_API_MAC_CARBON -DTARGET_API_MAC_OSX -fvisibility=hidden  -I/usr/X11R6/include -DXTHREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -force_cpusubtype_ALL -fpascal-strings -c ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c  -o build/SDL_RLEaccel.lo
libtool: compile:  gcc -g -O2 -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -DTARGET_API_MAC_CARBON -DTARGET_API_MAC_OSX -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/X11R6/include -DXTHREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -force_cpusubtype_ALL -fpascal-strings -c ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_RLEaccel.o
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:1168:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:1829:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:2566:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:2836:suffix or operands invalid for `movd'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:2934:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:3884:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:4433:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:4992:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:5207:suffix or operands invalid for `movd'
/var/folders/l_/_b6srsss7sggnnclplzx59280000gn/T//ccG8MUwb.s:5307:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
make: *** [build/SDL_RLEaccel.lo] Error 1
```

I've tried everything I could think of and done what I think is a fair amount of searching on this subject, but can't find anything that looks closely related.

Has anyone tried compiling SDL for Lion and succeeded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `./configure --disable-assembly`.

Comment: That did it. I obviously have much to learn about the `./configure`, `make`, `make install` process.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to take the performance hit of disabling all the assembly, it's actually a [one character change to fix the build on LLVM](http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1111).

Comment: It works. I got the "invalid instruction" error which seems to be suggesting the `movq` instruction is not supported at all. Still it was solved. Don't know why, who cares. Thanks.

Comment: BTW direct link to the changed character is http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/comparison/32f0f603a0c8/src/video/mmx.h I just modified the file by hand.