# SDL 1.3 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion Build Error

Tags: macos, build, sdl, osx-mountain-lion, llvm-gcc

I need to use SDL 1.3 for a project I want to start working on but I am having issues compiling it. Here is the terminal output: http://pastebin.com/Ucq6fkfj

I previously got the same problem as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169981/compiling-sdl-from-source-on-a-mac-running-os-x-10-7-lion) question and used the answer from it. I have Xcode 4.5.2 and recently updated my Xcode Command Line tools. I have gcc version `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to install X11 headers. I recently built SDL in OSX without problems, but encountered this one.

Check this (my project wiki - OSX point 3):
http://www.indielib.com/wiki/index.php?title=Building_IndieLib

And  this:
[https://github.com/Themaister/RetroArch/wiki/Compilation-guide-(OS-X)](https://github.com/Themaister/RetroArch/wiki/Compilation-guide-%28OS-X%29)

Also disabling assembly will impact performance, so I would not recommend it. I used ./configure without disabling assembly.

Comment: I already have XQuartz installed from when I installed Mono... My `./configure` with assembly gave the the error I linked to in the question. Any other ideas?

Comment: After updating XQuartz and Symlinking my X11 headers, I seem to get this error every time I try to build it: http://pastebin.com/WYPaFGZs